# es6 in webpack.config.babel.js reports 'SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word' when run with babel-loader 6

Tags: webpack, babeljs

With `babel-loader` 5, I can have es6 in `webpack.config.babel.js`. It fails, however, when I use babel-loader 6. Any ideas how to fix this? I have looked at the answers to similar questions and they seem to be addressing a situation where babel-loader 5 isused